# Why would one combine probabilties using a sqrt(-log) form?

Tags: probability, classification

I've been using a value, from a paper, combining two probabilities $P_A$ (for the probability that an event is A) and $P_B$ (for the probability that an event is B), where A/B are mutually exclusive origins for the event. Each variable uses separate classification techniques so that in principle they describe the same probability, usually $P_A \neq (1-P_B)$.

They are combined using the form:
$$
S = -(\sqrt{-\ln P_A} - \sqrt{-\ln P_B})
$$
Which, when run over a very large set of events with $P_A$, $P_B$ gives a single, nicely separated smooth parameter separating events as "Very" A ($\sim1$) or B ($\sim-1$), which we can then use to classify particular events using some cutoff (the general form with data ends up being two large peaks at around $\pm0.7$).

The problem is, I didn't design this combination and can't find any reference to why it was chosen/whether it is some standard method that I don't know the specifics of. In particular whilst I can find the odd reference discussing taking the log of a probability (usually in relation to numerical precision) I can't find anything that uses a square root.

I suspect I just don't know the right term/language to use to search, any ideas?

Comment: Any time I see -ln(P) I tend to think information rate or entropy.  In any case, I'm not sure what you mean by the A-ness of an event.  Is an event a large set of A or B outcomes (simple events) for which a single S is calculated?

Comment: No, each event, which in truth is "A" OR "B" has various different signal properties that are separately combined into a "Probability that event is A" and "Probability that event is B". So, they each measure the same thing, but with different information used for each calculation (so Pa neq (1-Pb) because of random errors) (edited to rephrase this part)

Comment: OK, gotcha.  Sorry, I don't know of a specific data or sensor fusion algorithm that uses that function.  However, plotting it in matlab yielded something interesting.  I noticed that if I let Pb = 1 - Pa (I know you said that wasn't automatically true, but perhaps in a noiseless model...) and plotted S vs PA I got a curve that looked a whole lot like sqrt(2) * erfinv( 2*PA-1 ), where 2*PA-1 just gives you a -1 to +1 versus 0 to 1 basis.